# How do I get the type of an atom in J?

Tags: j

Does J have any kind of reflection? I couldn't find anything in the documentation, though I may have missed it.

Comment: That's an info about a new language for me. I did a search and found `type x` returns the type of `x`. http://www.elliscave.com/APL_J/Learning_J.pdf

Comment: `type` is a convenience cover for the foreign `4!:0`. If given the name of an object it will tell you the class of that name. For example: `type 'names'` will return the boxed literal `verb`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type is given by foreign `3!:0`.

See: http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/dx003.htm

Comment: The base library also provides a cover (`datatype`) for `3!:0` that gives a literal description of a noun's type.